# Can I associate a single shared access policy to more than one event hub (topic)?

Tags: azure-eventhub

If I have to give similar permission on more than 1 event hub, then I need to create separate shared access policy for each event hub individually. Is there a way where I can create a shared access policy and associate that with more than 1 event hub?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to have an N:N mapping between eventhubs and policies. Though, you can create the policy at namespace level which will naturally apply to all eventhubs of that namespace. I wonder if that would address you ask.

Comment: My use case is that I have 4 event hubs 'A',  'B', 'C' and 'D' (Kafka API). To my service clients I need to give 'Listen' permission to 'A' and 'C' and 'Send' permission to 'B' and 'D'. To achieve this now I need to create 4 policies one for each event hub. This demands clients to setup different Kafka producers and listeners for each event hub which I feel is an overhead.

Comment: Have you checked RBAC? RBAC will probably address your issue where instead of having one policy per topic, with RBAC you can have 2 secure identities where one has permission to send and the other permission to receive.